# C# New class file can't get button to work now.

Tags: c#, xaml

I am creating a new class file for my program So I moved some code to this new

```
namespace App1
{
    class BL_PageContent
    {
        public static string VarOutput { get; set; }

        async public void btnCourse1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] names = new string[3] { "COP3488C,", "UWP1,", "This course is mobile app development." };
            await WorkerAsync(names);
        }


        async private void btnCourse2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] names = new string[3] { "DOP3488B,", "UWC1,", "This course is Cloud Computing." };
            await WorkerAsync(names);
        }

        async private void btnCourse3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string[] names = new string[3] { "BOP3589,", "UWP2,", "This course Computer Programming Java 1." };
            await WorkerAsync(names);

        }

        private async Task WorkerAsync(string[] names)
        {
            string VarOutput = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                VarOutput = VarOutput + names[i] + "  ";
            }


        }
    }
}
```

This is my main class file for the app.

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{




    public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
        txtBoxRas.Text = "Rasmussen College";
        txtBoxRas.FontSize = 14;

        txtBoxRas.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);

    }
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessCalc();
    }

    private void ProcessCalc()
    {
        Int32 Var1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxInput1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxInput2.Text);
        txtBoxDisplay.Text = Convert.ToString(Var1);
    }


    private async Task WorkerAsync(string[] names)
    {

        txtBoxCourse.Text = BL_PageContent.VarOutput;
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(BL_PageContent.VarOutput);
        await dialog.ShowAsync();


    }



}
```

}

And this is my xaml for my display. And this is were the errors are coming up what is the issue I know it must be linking to this file? Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1061 'MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'btnCourse1_Click' and no extension method 'btnCourse1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'MainPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.643,0.234">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBoxRas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,95,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Rasmussen logo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="42" Width="230" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.358,1.105"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBoxDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="470,195,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Result" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="57" Width="191"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxInput1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,142,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="48" Width="140"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxInput2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="510,142,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="48" Width="151"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnSubmit" Content="add it up!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="393,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="268" Click="btnSubmit_Click"/>
    <HyperlinkButton x:Uid="hlkWebSite" Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,268,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Button x:Name="btnCourse1" Content="Course 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,337,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnCourse1_Click"/>

    <Button x:Name="btnCourse2" Content="Course 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,374,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnCourse2_Click"/>

    <Button x:Name="btnCourse3" Content="Course 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,411,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnCourse3_Click"/>



    <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxCourse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,337,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Course Info" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="106" Width="303"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It was what we were told to do for the assignment not sure why probably we will be building out that class more but not sure. So I have to have btnCourse1_Click() on main page?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. See this code in XAML:

```
Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
```

Your XAML contains the information about where to find code behind for the view. As it is clearly stated above, it is `App1.MainPage`. So you XAML is then looking for these in `MainPage`:

```
<Button x:Name="btnCourse1" Content="Course 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,337,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnCourse1_Click"/>

<Button x:Name="btnCourse2" Content="Course 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,374,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnCourse2_Click"/>

// ... so on
```

and it is no longer there because you moved it. So it is complaining. There is no reason you should be doing this. If this is an attempt to refactor or move the code for re-usability, this is not the way to do it.

If you want to reuse code, create reusable classes and then pass those to your viewmodel. Bind your view to your viewmodel.